# Error when trying to save an Excel file from attribute table using QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, csv

I keep getting this error (see below) when trying to save the attribute table to an Excel file using XY Tools. Can anyone help? I have deleted and re-installed `xytools` but this hasn't helped.

> An error has occured while executing Python code:
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/Doug/.qgis2/python/plugins\xytools\xytools.py", line 301, in excelSave
> xlw.writeAttributeRow(rowNr, values)
> File "C:/Users/Doug/.qgis2/python/plugins\xytools\providers\excel.py", line
> ```
>
> 57, in writeAttributeRow
>       self.ws.write(rowNr, colNr, cell)
>       File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1030, in write
>       self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
>       File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1078, in row
>       self.**rows[indx] = self.Row(indx, self)
>       File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\xlwt\Row.py", line 42, in __init**
>       raise ValueError("row index (%r) not an int in range(65536)" % rowx)
>       ValueError: row index (65536) not an int in range(65536)
>
> Python version:
>   2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
>
> QGIS version:
>   2.6.1-Brighton Brighton, e2a51df

Comment: The "not an int range(65536)" message seems to allude the format that you are saving to may not support more than 65536 records, http://superuser.com/questions/366468/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-rows-in-a-microsoft-excel-xls-or-xlsx

Comment: Thanks Joseph. This is a neat plug-in. Worked perfectly!

Comment: Awesome buddy, glad you got it working! Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others, but also note that there are a number of methods to get what you're looking for, some of which have already been posted by others :)

Answer (score 1):

> ValueError("row index (%r) not an int in range(65536)" % rowx)
>   ValueError: row index (65536) not an int in range(65536)

indicates that the number of rows is to large. `*.xls` has a max number of rows according to [this post](https://superuser.com/a/366473).

You could try to save it as `*.xlsx` or split the records or try it with another plugin as Joseph suggests.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround where you can select all attributes by hitting the left uppermost in the attribute table

[image]

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy all the attributes

Open excel and paste the features

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

As my comment suggests, you need to save to a newer version of excel (v2007 or >) to save a GIS table that has more than 65536 records.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the **MMQGIS** plugin which, when enabled, could be accessed from the Toolbar:

*MMQGIS > Import / Export > **Attributes Export to CSV File***

Hope this helps!